# Create a value adding two columns together

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I am attempting to define and new column called `End Year` that is the calculation of another column plus a number representing number of years. For some reason my script does not recognize the new column called `Allocation Year` using the excerpt below SQL statement in SQL Server 2008. Note that `Contract Year` is an existing column that is identified in the non-redacted full script:

```
,[Allocation Type] =
CASE 
WHEN left([contract type] ,1)'1' = THEN 'O&M'
ELSE 'N/A'
END
,[Allocation Year] =
CASE
WHEN [Contract Year]='XXXX' THEN '0'
ELSE CAST ([Contract Year] AS INT)
END
,[End Year] =
CASE
WHEN [Allocation Type]='O&M' THEN [Allocation Year] + 6
END
```

Comment: To confirm, you're adding a column to a query result - not an actual table?

Comment: I think you are missing an ELSE on your last CASE.

Comment: Yes, I figure it best to be created on the view instead of a permanent column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Columns are named with the `AS` keyword (which can also be elided in many cases), not with the `=` operator.

SQL Server does not let you reference other columns or aliases in a `SELECT` clause - you have to use a subquery:

Like so:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN [Allocation Type] = 'O&M'
        THEN [Allocation Year Temp] + 6
        ELSE NULL
    END AS [Allocation Year]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN LEFT( [Contract type], 1 ) = '1'
            THEN 'O&M'
            ELSE 'N/A'
        END AS [Allocation Type],

        CASE WHEN [Contract Year] = 'XXXX' 
            THEN '0'
            ELSE CAST( [Contract Year] AS int )
        END AS [Allocation Year Temp],
        *
    FROM
        ....
)
```

Comment: *Columns are named with the AS keyword, not with the = operator.*, actually you can do both in SQL Server.

Comment: *SQL Server does not let you reference other columns or aliases in a SELECT clause*, perhaps all databases don't let you do that. Do you know any database that does?

Comment: @RacilHilan I know at least MySQL and PostgreSQL do let you reference aliases without needing a subquery.

Comment: Do you know that they do, or do you think they do? Do you have a reference, or can you provide an SQL Fiddle? AFAIK neither of them does, nor Oracle too. And you mentioned SQL Server, so none of the major databases allows that.

Comment: @RacilHilan My apologies - I was thinking of how they let you use aliases in `WHERE`.

Comment: Not even in `WHERE`. The only place you can use them is in `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put everything in one select query, then try this one. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
,[End Year] =
CASE
WHEN left([contract type] ,1)='1' THEN 
  (CASE
    WHEN [Contract Year]='XXXX' THEN 6
   ELSE (CAST ([Contract Year] AS INT) + 6 )
  END)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference computed columns in the `SELECT` statement. You'll have to repeat the calculation (or use subqueries like Dai suggested):

```
,[Allocation Type] =
CASE 
WHEN left([contract type] ,1)='1' THEN 'O&M'
ELSE 'N/A'
END
,[Allocation Year] =
CASE
WHEN [Contract Year]='XXXX' THEN 0
ELSE CAST ([Contract Year] AS INT)
END
,[End Year] =
CASE
WHEN left([contract type] ,1)='1' THEN (CASE
                                        WHEN [Contract Year]='XXXX' THEN 0
                                        ELSE CAST ([Contract Year] AS INT)
                                        END) + 6
END
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. this helped!